# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources

Tags: jsf, primefaces, nullpointerexception, resources

I have a Spring + JSP application (MyFaces + PrimeFaces) and I've added a filter to it in order to add the same headers to all responses.

The application is working fine but if I restart the server and someone has an open page (with a now invalid or non-existing session) I start getting NullPointerException all the time, but it's happening outside of my code. How can I fix this?

The problem seems to be in org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils:66 (getComponentResources(FacesContext context)) where it tries this:

```
List<UIComponent> resources = context.getViewRoot().getComponentResources(context, "head");
```

But context.getViewRoot() returns null so it fails.

If the client reloads the page, he is redirected to the login page correctly, a new session is created, and errors stop.

**NoCacheFilter class:**

```
@WebFilter(servletNames = { "Faces Servlet" })
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
        if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {
            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

**Exception Trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources(ResourceUtils.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:280)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:107)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.renderAjaxError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:238)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:61)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:217)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at eu.calabacin.controller.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at eu.calabacin.controller.GlobalFilter.doFilter(GlobalFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Section of web.xml where GlobalFilter is defined:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GlobalFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>eu.calabacin.controller.GlobalFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GlobalFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**GlobalFilter class:**

```
public class GlobalFilter implements Filter {

    private final static String LOGIN_PAGE = "/" + GlobalService.LOGIN_PAGE + ".xhtml";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);// don't create a session if there isn't one
        if (session != null && !session.isNew()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            redirectToLogin(request, response, chain);
        }
    }

    private void redirectToLogin(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String pathInfo = httpRequest.getServletPath();
        if (pathInfo == null || !pathInfo.equalsIgnoreCase(LOGIN_PAGE)) {
            String newUrl = httpRequest.getContextPath() + LOGIN_PAGE;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(newUrl);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

**Software versions:**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <myfaces.version>2.2.8</myfaces.version>
    <primefaces.version>6.0</primefaces.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

I guess I could 'fix' the problem by changing the ResourceUtils class checking if context.getViewRoot() returns null before trying to use it, but I'm sure I must be doing something wrong somewhere that causes this to fail.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or how I could fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Tried the latest PrimeFaces from github source? If I remember correctly there have been some changes in this regard. See the issuelist in github and the PrimeFaces forum.

Comment: @Kukeltje So you are saying this is a known bug?

Comment: I **think** I remember seeing posts about an NPE in relation to viewroot. I don't have the time to actually look this up

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into a similar problem (having a NullPointerException exactly at the same PrimeFaces line).

I solved the problem **upgrading** from Primefaces 6.0 to Primefaces 6.1 **and** correcting a wrong JPA query that was causing a previous exception (I'm not completely sure which action solved the problem, but I guess it was the upgrade).